# How do you position an img to rest above a div in HTML and css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to create a new front end for Google Search as part of CS50W. I'm trying to position the google logo image to rest on top of the searchbar, This is my HTML

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search">
            <img src="google_images_logo.jpg" class="imglogo">
            <div class="searchbar">
```

And this is my CSS

```css
#imglogo {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.searchbar {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 582px;
    height: 44px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Currently the logo just sits in the top-left corner.
I'd like the end result to be something like what the actual google/google image search page, with the logo centered just above the searchbar.

[image: what is currently happening]

That's what's happening right now with the code I currently have.

Comment: can you share an example of what you want?

Comment: @humming_bee57 please share an example or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit ur css and html like this..
As u didn't provide enough html so i don't know the complete structure..
Please put ur google image link, with this link which i added (wikipedia's google image link).

```css
#imglogo {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.logo {
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.searchbar {
  border-radius: 50px;
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 582px;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo img {
    height: 92px;
    width: 272px;
}
.form {
      position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="https://google.com/search">
<div class="logo">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/736px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" class="imglogo">
  </div>
  
  <div class="searchbar">

  </div>
</form>
```